# Object seperation in an image with OpenCVsharp

Tags: opencv, image-processing, c#-4.0

I'm trying to separate some leaves(objects in image) from an image like below

[Input Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9byGNxRMzS_aXdRSTFvcnE3VlE/view?usp=sharing)

the output should look like this picture below

[Output Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9byGNxRMzS_SEJaYlZSX3FUV00/view?usp=sharing)

I use OpenCvsharp in Visual studio 2010 (C# language)
I want to separate 4-5 leaves which are visible more than 80% of the complete leaf in the image, and get output image as the second image.
Please someone tell me how can achieve this?
I used watershed algorithm which is described [here](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/tree/master/sample/CStyleSamplesCS/Samples)

but I couldn't get any segments rather than one segment covering the whole image. I want to know if there's any better approaches(algorithms) to do this?

I'm doing this kind of thing because after I separated that 4-5 leaves, that image is again processed for brown spots on those leaves and shape of the edge to identify some diseases again using image processing. Please someone who has knowledge in this area help me..

Comment: After reading some same kind of researches I got to know this problem is relate to "clustering". Is it right? If so can I use K-means algorithm? How to use it for my problem? Or the solution is region growing(Segmentation) ?